# http paranoia/concern

Tags: networking, server, security

I am currently creating a personal "local" website. I do not plan on port fowarding to make it accessible to those outside my network. Will that be good enough for security, what about people on the same local network as I am, how can I block any other pcs from accessing my website, or password protect it?

I feel that http is not needed for this type of setup due to it being a local website, but I have connection to many APIs: Google Maps API, Facebook API, etc. Can my site be compromised without having http?

-Thanks, this community's support has always been fantastic!

Comment: This is better suited for security.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question is not related to Ubuntu, even if you are an Ubuntu user yourself.

Comment: Do you mean HTTPS?

Answer (score 3):

Bind your webserver to 127.0.0.1, then you will only be able to access the site locally.

Comment: unless someone has access to his machine, then they can portforward through ssh. But that's just a thought ;)

Comment: Thanks for all you answers, and sorry for the off-topic subject :)